# amadeus flight booking engine prototype showing error on local host

Tags: amadeus

amadeus flight booking engine prototype showing error on local host
ValueError('Missing required argument: {0}'.format(key)) ValueError: Missing required argument: client_id

prototype not working

Comment: Have you provided the API credentials ,secret and client_id correctly? Was this error faced on the code or on postman ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and check the ["How to Ask" guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)